# Double click the desktop to hide/show all icons

Tags: nautilus

Is there a way to make double-clicking an empty space on the desktop hide/show all desktop icons?

hint; the command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false` can be used with an if statement, but how do I make it execute by a double click?

Comment: Better use a keyboard shortcut to toggle. Double click has another functionality.